# How do I join an NSSet's elements to create an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsset

If I have an `NSSet` of `NSString` objects, how can I join them together to create a single `NSString`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`NSSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `-allObjects` method will return an `NSArray` of objects in the receiver.

So, knowing this, it's pretty simple:

```
[[set allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: However, be aware that "The order of the objects in the array isn’t defined."